# Financial Time Series Downsampling with Polars and OOP implementation

Tags: python, time-series, python-polars

I have a demo financial time series downsampling module:

```py
from typing import Union, List
import polars as pl
from polars.testing import assert_frame_equal, assert_frame_not_equal
import numpy as np
import numba
import datetime

class TimeSeriesDownSampling:
    """ Performs sampling and aggregation from consolidated trades and quotes (CTQ) of financial assets.
    """
    data: pl.LazyFrame = pl.LazyFrame()
    agg_data: Union[pl.DataFrame, pl.LazyFrame] = None # aggregated data

    def __init__(self, date_col: str, datetime_col: str, identifier_col: str, price_col: str, size_col:str, pre_market:bool=False, post_market:bool=False):

        self.date_col = date_col
        self.datetime_col = datetime_col
        self.identifier_col = identifier_col
        self.price_col = price_col
        self.size_col = size_col
        self.pre_market = pre_market
        self.post_market = post_market

    def generate_sample(self, data) -> Union[pl.LazyFrame, pl.DataFrame]:
        assert_frame_not_equal(data, self.data)
        self.data = data
        assert self.agg_data is not None, "The sampling and aggregation has not been performed, you should call this method after computation."

        if self.collect:
            return self.agg_data.collect()
        return self.agg_data
    
    @staticmethod
    def calculate_ohlcv(price_col:str, size_col:str, datetime_col:str="datetime", bar_times:bool=False, 
                        ohlcv_alias:dict={"open": "open", "high":"high", "low":"low", "close":"close", "volume":"volume"}) -> List[pl.Expr]:
        """ Calculate OHLCV data from the groupby object.
        """
        ohlcv_expr = [
        pl.len().alias("number_of_trades"),
        pl.col(price_col).first().alias(ohlcv_alias["open"]),
        pl.col(price_col).max().alias(ohlcv_alias["high"]),
        pl.col(price_col).min().alias(ohlcv_alias["low"]),
        pl.col(price_col).last().alias(ohlcv_alias["close"]),
        pl.col(size_col).sum().alias(ohlcv_alias["volume"])
        ] # This is a list of Polars expressions that can be used to calculate the OHLCV data later during the aggregation process.

        if bar_times:
            ohlcv_expr.append(pl.col(datetime_col).first().alias("first_trade_time"))
            ohlcv_expr.append(pl.col(datetime_col).last().alias("last_trade_time"))

        return ohlcv_expr

    @staticmethod
    def filter_trading_hours(data: pl.LazyFrame, datetime_col:str="datetime", pre_market:bool=False, post_market:bool=False) -> pl.LazyFrame:
        """ Filter the data to only include trading hours.
        """
        if not pre_market and not post_market:
            data = (data
                    .filter(pl.col(datetime_col).dt.time() >= datetime.time(9, 30, 0))
                    .filter(pl.col(datetime_col).dt.time() < datetime.time(16, 0, 0))
                    )
        elif pre_market and post_market:
            pass
        elif pre_market:
            data = data.filter(pl.col(datetime_col).dt.time() < datetime.time(4, 0, 0))
        elif post_market:
            data = data.filter(pl.col(datetime_col).dt.time() >= datetime.time(9, 30, 0))
            
        return data
    
class TimeBarSampling(TimeSeriesDownSampling):
    """ Performs time-based sampling and aggregation from consolidated trades and quotes (CTQ) of financial assets.
    """

    def __init__(self, date_col: str, datetime_col: str, identifier_col: str, price_col: str, size_col:str, rule:str, 
                 closed:str="left", label:str="left", upsample:bool=False, pre_market:bool=False, post_market:bool=False):
        """ Constructor for TimeBarSampling.
        :param rule: The time rule to resample the data
        :type rule: Union[pd.Timedelta, str]
        """
        super().__init__(date_col, datetime_col, identifier_col, price_col, size_col, pre_market, post_market)
        self.rule = rule
        self.closed = closed
        self.label = label

    def generate_sample(self, data: Union[pl.LazyFrame, pl.DataFrame], collect:bool=True) -> Union[pl.LazyFrame, pl.DataFrame]:
        self.collect = collect
        
        if not isinstance(data.select(pl.col(self.date_col)).dtypes[0], pl.Date):
            data = data.with_columns(pl.col(self.date_col).cast(pl.Date))
            
        data = self.filter_trading_hours(data, self.datetime_col, self.pre_market, self.post_market)
        data = data.sort([self.identifier_col, self.date_col, self.datetime_col])

        self.agg_data = data.group_by_dynamic(self.datetime_col, every=self.rule,
                                              by=[self.identifier_col, self.date_col],
                                              label=self.label, closed=self.closed)
        self.agg_data = self.agg_data.agg(self.calculate_ohlcv(self.price_col, self.size_col))
        self.agg_data = self.agg_data.sort([self.identifier_col, self.date_col])
        
        return super().generate_sample(data)
    
    def generate_sample_from_files(self, files_dir_path:str, collect:bool=True) -> Union[pl.LazyFrame, pl.DataFrame]:
        self.collect = collect
        
        data = pl.concat([
                pl.scan_parquet(f"{files_dir_path}/{files}")
                .filter(pl.col("datetime").dt.time() >= datetime.time(9, 30, 0))
                .filter(pl.col("datetime").dt.time() < datetime.time(16, 0, 0))
                .sort([self.identifier_col, self.date_col, self.datetime_col])
                .group_by_dynamic(self.datetime_col, every=self.rule, by=[self.identifier_col, self.date_col], label=self.label, closed=self.closed)
                .agg(
                    self.calculate_ohlcv(self.price_col, self.size_col))
                    for files in os.listdir(f"{files_dir_path}")], how="vertical")
        
        self.agg_data = data.sort([self.identifier_col, self.date_col, self.datetime_col])
        
        return super().generate_sample(data)
```

The above module takes an input of consolidated quotes and trades (CQT equity tick data) and downsample according to time periods (5 mins).

Example function call is as the following:

```py
timebar_sampler = TimeBarSampling(date_col="date", datetime_col="datetime", identifier_col="ticker", price_col="price", size_col="size", rule="5m")

timebar_sampler.generate_sample_from_files(f"{wct_dir}/wct_test_3days")
```

The reason why that I do not use the `generate_sample` method with glob pattern `pl.scan_parquet("*.parquet")` is because that each day of the CQT dataset contains about 70 million rows. I only need the aggregated (resampled) datasets. By tricking the Polars queries to follow the pipeline `concat(read-preprocess-downsample-ready)`, I can achieve apporopirate memory memory management as well as significant speed boosts.

[image]

**The problem:**

I want to integrate the above process with the OOP module. However, I have troble integrating the `filter_trading_hours` method within the `generate_sample_from_files` method. Specifically, to robustly replce

```py
.filter(pl.col("datetime").dt.time() >= datetime.time(9, 30, 0))
.filter(pl.col("datetime").dt.time() < datetime.time(16, 0, 0))
```